# Как запустить Makefile из .travis.yml?

Tags: makefile, непрерывная-интеграция, yml, travis, travis-ci

Мне нужно запустить утилиту make из файла .travis.yml и выполнить команду из Makefile.

Что я должен написать в .travis.yml?

Answer (score 0):

## .travis.yml

```
script: make command_name
```